# How to prove the sequence $ \frac{c^n}{\sqrt{n}}, c \in (0, 1)$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $a_n = \frac{c^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $c \in (0, 1), n = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$, how to prove that the sequence is convergent? What if $c \in (0, \infty)$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \leq 1$.

Comment: Either prove that the sequence is Cauchy or guess that its limit is $0$ and use the definition of convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats because if $c \in (0, 1]$ then $0 \le a_n \le 1/\sqrt{n}$ and $1/\sqrt{n} \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

If $c >1$ then $\frac{c^n}{n} \le \frac{c^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ but $\frac{c^n}{n} \to \infty$, thus $\frac{c^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges

Comment: we are talking about sequences $a_i$ not series $\sum_i a_i$